# How to access the Twitter API after login with Django social auth?

Tags: django, twitter, django-socialauth

I would like to play with the twitter API, but I'm lost with how access the API, get TimeLine, RT, etc, after login with django social auth.

Can anyone provide an example of another twitter library that I can use to access streaming, timeline, etc. after authenticating with Django social Auth?

I'm checking [tweepy](https://github.com/tweepy/) but I can't see how to use it if I don't need to use the tweepy auth method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This example from the Django-social-auth docs](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tokens.html) shows what you need:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> from social_auth.models import UserSocialAuth
>>> instance = UserSocialAuth.objects.filter(provider='twitter').get(...)
>>> pprint(instance.tokens)
{u'oauth_token': u'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
 u'_token_secret': u'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'}
```

The UserSocialAuth model will automatically store the access tokens you need. You access them via the `tokens` attribute.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the tokens from the UserSocialAuth instance associated to the user:

```
try:
        instance = UserSocialAuth.objects.filter(user=request.user).get()
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return redirect(getattr(settings,'LOGIN_URL','/login/twitter/'))
```

After retrieving the instance, get the keys:

```
oauth_access_token=(instance.tokens).get('oauth_token')
oauth_access_secret=(instance.tokens).get('oauth_token_secret')
```

With the token and secret, you can now connect to twitter using the package of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

When a user grants your app access to Twitter, you'll get an access token & access token secret. Save it on your db. You use that to access the API.

Example is at: https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/examples/oauth.py